# EmberJS - Set active based on index

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using EmberJS with a background of AngularJS and maybe this is causing me problems in what I am trying to achieve. I have a list of elements inside a `<ul>` and I want to use the keyboard to navigate through them. Basically, when I press up, I decrement the selectedIndex and when I press down, I increment it.

In my view, I want to compare the index of the element with the selectedIndex variable and assign it the `active` class if they are equal. Now, in AngularJS I could use `ng-class="getClass($index)"` and I would be done.

In EmberJS however, I don't know what is the best way to do it. I have read that maybe I could create my own helper, or use a collectionView. It seems to me a little overkill to create a helper for a simple comparison.

Currently, here's my emberJS code:

In template.hbs:

```
<div id="command-manager">
    <div class="right-inner-addon">
      {{input id="searchInput" type="search" class="form-control" onEvent="keyUp" action="search" placeholder="{{t command-manager.searchInput.placeholder }}" maxlength="32"}}
       <a {{ action "clearSearch" }} class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="suggestions">

        <ul>
            {{#each suggestion in cm.suggestions.elements}}
                <li class="{{ cm.suggestions.getClass(index)}}">{{ suggestion.show }}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

In my component.hbs:

```
var CommandManagerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  cm: new CommandManager(),

  keyUp: function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode === 38) { // up arrow
      this.get('cm').changeSuggestion('up');
      console.log('up arrow');
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 40) { //down arrow
      this.get('cm').changeSuggestion('down');
      console.log('down arrow');
    }
    else {
      this.get('cm').receiveCommand(e.target.value);
    }


  },

  didInsertElement: function() {
  },
  actions:{
    search:function(text) {
      this.get('cm').receiveCommand(text);
    },
    clearSearch: function() {
      $('#searchInput').val('');
      this.get('cm').clearSuggestions();
    }
  }
});

export default CommandManagerComponent;
```

In my commandManager file
¸

```
var suggestions = Ember.Object.extend({
    getClass: function(index) {
      if(index == this.get('selected')) {
        return 'active';
      }
    }.property('selected')
  })

  self.suggestions = suggestions.create({
    'elements': Ember.A(),
    'selected' : -1
  });

  self.changeSuggestion = function(direction) {
    var selectedSuggestion = self.suggestions.get('selected');


    if(direction == 'up') {
      if(selectedSuggestion <= 0) {
        selectedSuggestion = self.suggestions.elements.toArray().length - 1;
      }
      else {
        selectedSuggestion--;
      }
    }
    else if(direction == 'down') {
      if(selectedSuggestion >= (self.suggestions.elements.toArray().length - 1)) {
        selectedSuggestion = 0;
      }
      else {
        selectedSuggestion++;
      }
    }

    self.suggestions.set('selected', selectedSuggestion);

    console.log(self.suggestions);
  };
```

So, I was planning on using `{{ cm.suggestions.getClass(index)}}` to return the class but I'm feeling that is not the best way to do it.

If someone can guide me on this I would really appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of what you describe, it may help you a bit

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xareberi/1/edit

**js**

```
App.Option = Ember.Object.extend({
  id:null,
  name:null,
  isSelected:false
});

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  selectedOptionIndex:0,
  keyUp: function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 38) { // up arrow
      if(this.get("selectedOptionIndex")>0){
       this.decrementProperty("selectedOptionIndex"); 
      }
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 40) { //down arrow
      console.log('down arrow');
      if(this.get("selectedOptionIndex")<this.get("options").length-1){
       this.incrementProperty("selectedOptionIndex"); 
      }
    }
  },
  updateSelectedOption:function(){
    this.get("options").setEach("isSelected",false);
    this.get("options")[this.get("selectedOptionIndex")].set("isSelected",true);
  }.observes("selectedOptionIndex"),
  options:[
    App.Option.create({id:1,name:"option 1",isSelected:true}),
    App.Option.create({id:2,name:"option 2"}),
    App.Option.create({id:3,name:"option 3"}),
    App.Option.create({id:4,name:"option 4"})
  ]

});
```

**hbs**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
      <i>please click on options and press key up/down</i>
      <div tabindex="0" style="outline:none">
      <ul>
      {{#each option in view.options}}
      <li {{bind-attr class="option.isSelected:active"}}>{{option.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
      </div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Em.ArrayProxy` and `Em.ObjectProxy` in combination.

The target is clear. U need an `isSelected` property on each item in the list. So use the possibilities of databinding to create this property.

So, lets say we have data like the following:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'one'
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'two'
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'three'
}]
```

Now, u *could* put a `isSelected` property on them, but thats probably not what u want!
But a ObjectProxy can give u an additional layer to define this property.

```
var maySelectedItem = Em.ObjectProxy.extend({
    content: null,
    currentIndex: null,
    allItems: null,
    isSelected: function() {
        // just find out if its selected:
        return this.get('allItems') && this.get('allItems').indexOf(this.get('content')) == this.get('currentIndex') || "NO";
    }.property('content', 'allItems.@each', 'currentIndex')
});
```

Now u have a nice ObjectProxy. I've nulled the `content`, `currentIndex` and `allItems` to make sure they wont get proxied to the `content` property then everything else, and to make clear that they should be set then creating an instance of that class.

Soo, Now u need to transform your array of Objects with the data that u want to an array of maySelectedItems. U could use `[].map` but its much cooler to use live data binding with Em.ArrayProxy:

```
var maySelectedItemList = Em.ArrayProxy.extend({
    content: null,
    currentIndex: null,
    objectAtContent: function(idx) {
        return maySelectedItem.create({
            content: this.get('content').objectAt(idx),
            outerArrayProxy: this,
            allItemsBinding: 'outerArrayProxy.content',
            currentIndexBinding: 'outerArrayProxy.currentIndex'
        });
    }
});
```

So, now u have everything u need! Just use it:

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
    content: null, // the array of items
    selectedIndex: 0,
    innerContent: function() {
        return maySelectedItemList.create({
            outerController: this,
            contentBinding: 'outerController.content',
            currentIndexBinding: 'outerController.selectedIndex'
        });
    }.property('content')
});
```

Look the result here:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yewuboga/4/edit